# Case Escalation

Tags: case, escalation

I have a requirement where case should get escalated after 3 hours, once the case is escalated it should be assigned to owner's manager.
Can someone help me here

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! If you are asking for generally what is the best route to take (e.g., Apex trigger, scheduled Flow), then this should be an acceptable question for SFSE. Please edit your question to specify that is the information for which you are asking. However, asking for specific code is not an acceptable question here. This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escalation rules automatically escalate cases when the case meets the criteria defined in the rule entry. You can create rule entries, which define criteria for escalating a case, and escalation actions, which define what happens when a case escalates.

Refer the [Set Up Escalation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rules_escalation_create.htm&type=5)